# Haskell inheritance, data, constructors

Tags: haskell, inheritance

So I want to define multiple data classes for my Asteroids game/assignment:

```
data One = One {oneVelocity :: Velocity, onePosition :: Position, (((other properties unique to One)))}
data Two = Two {twoVelocity :: Velocity, twoPosition :: Position, (((other properties unique to Two)))}
data Three = Three {threeVelocity :: Velocity, threePosition :: Position, (((other properties unique to Three)))}
```

As you can see I have multiple data classes with some overlapping properties (velocity, position). That also meant that I had to give them different names per data class ("oneVelocity", "twoVelocity", ...).

**Is there a way I can let these types of data extend something?** I thought of using one datatype with multiple constructors, but some of these current data classes are very different and I don't thing they should reside in one data class with multiple constructors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should probably use just a single data type for all of these, but *parameterised* on the specific details:

```
data MovingObj s = MovingObj
        { velocity :: Velocity
        , position :: Position
        , specifics :: s }
```

Then you can create e.g. `asteroid :: MovingObj AsteroidSpecifics`, but you can also write functions that work with any such moving object like

```
advance :: TimeStep -> MovingObj s -> MovingObj s
advance h (MovingObj v p s) = MovingObj v (p .+^ h*^v) s
```

Comment: `asteroid :: MovingObj AsteroidSpecifics`, you mean that you create a function asteroid that you give a MovingObj instance and you get an AsteroidSpecifics data type in return?

So say the size of the asteroid is saved in AsteroidSpecifics, to get this I would do: 

`size (asteroid movingObjInstance)`?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat there are no instances involved, and `asteriod` is just a value, not a function, but yeah, you'd store the size in `AsteroidSpecifics`.

Comment: So AsteroidSpecifics would be another data type?

Comment: Yes, one of three type each of which contains what's needed for an asteriod and for the other object flavours, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

There is no inheritance in Haskell (at least, not the kind you associate with object-oriented classes). You just want composition of data types.

```
data Particle = Particle { velocity :: Velocity
                         , position :: Position 
                         }

-- Exercise for the reader: research the GHC extension that
-- allows all three of these types to use the same name `p`
-- for the particle field.
data One = One { p1 :: Particle
               , ... }
data Two = Two { p2 :: Particle
               , ... }
data Three = Three { p3 :: Particle
                   , ... }
```

Or, you can define a type that encapsulates the other properties, and let those be added to different kinds of `Particle`s.

```
data Properties = One { ... } 
                | Two { ... }
                | Three { ... }

data Particle = Particle { velocity :: Velocity
                         , position :: Position
                         , properties :: Properties
                         }
```

(Or see [@leftaroundabout's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52896589/1126841), which is a nicer way of handling this approach.)

Comment: The `p` in `One { p :: Particle}` and `Two { p :: Particle}` cannot be identical, right?

Comment: But this means there is no easy way to extract for example the velocity of data One? With inheritance in C# for example you could just pretend like velocity sat inside One, but here you seem to first have to extract the particle and then the velocity?

Comment: There's an extension you can enable in newer versions (8 or later?) to allow duplicate record fields, but since I'm not that familiar with it (I can't even remember  its name), I'll just fix it.

Comment: Like I said, Haskell doesn't support inheritance; using composition, you get the velocity of the particle contained in the value, not the velocity of the value itself. The second one may be closer, as the specific constructor used for the `properties` fields is somewhat analogous to a "subclass" of `Particle`.

Comment: The extension is [DuplicateRecordFields](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#duplicate-record-fields)

Comment: @4castle yes, but I dispute that it makes sense to use it, certainly not here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Why do you dispute its use here?

Comment: `DuplicateRecordFields` just hacks around the limitations of traditional Haskell records, without really addressing the fundamental reason for these limitations. The proposal that does it properly is [`OverloadedRecordFields`](https://github.com/adamgundry/ghc-proposals/blob/overloaded-record-fields/proposals/0000-overloaded-record-fields.rst) (still experimental?); IMO use either that or stick to Haskell98 ways of dealing with records (i.e. avoid duplicate field names in the first place).

Comment: For the first solution, you can also define a typeclass `HasParticle` and then functions to get velocity and position in its terms, which will work for all of `One`, `Two` and `Three`.